# Trying to make a view with a sample database and cannot seem to get it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I am trying to create a view for products with English descriptions in ascending order. Also titling it `LastName_vProductLinesUSA`.

Here are some screenshots of the database:

1. [Database overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31xAb.png)
2. [SalesLT.vProductandDescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnR45.png)
3. [SalesLT.Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO2Ob.png)
4. [SalesLT.ProductDescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOyeu.png)

I have tried using the query:

```
CREATE VIEW LastName_vProductLinesUSA 
AS 
    SELECT 
        [ProductID], [Name], [ProductModel], [Description] 
    FROM 
        [SalesLT.vProductAndDescription] 
    ORDER BY
        [Description];
```

But when I try to execute the query I get this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure LastName_vProductLinesUSA, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Read the error message. What do you think you should change?

Comment: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views` <--- this is why.

Comment: Aside: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ORDER BY from the view:

```
CREATE VIEW LastName_vProductLinesUSA 
AS SELECT [ ProductID ], [ Name ], [ ProductModel ], [ Description ] 
FROM [ SalesLT.vProductAndDescription ] 
ORDER BY [ Description ] ; <--- remove this
```

Without it:

```
CREATE VIEW LastName_vProductLinesUSA 
AS SELECT [ ProductID ], [ Name ], [ ProductModel ], [ Description ] 
FROM [ SalesLT.vProductAndDescription ]
```

If you want order to the results, order when you select from the view:

```
SELECT * FROM LastName_vProductLinesUSA
ORDER BY [ Description ] ;
```

Side note, on style; square brackets are fairly ugly. If you're trying to make them prettier by surrounding them with spaces, consider removing the square brackets instead (and strive to not use reserved words for identifiers so that you can carry on avoiding using [ ])

Comment: If you absolutely need the have a sort order on a view, ypu need to add `TOP 100 PERCENT` hint

Answer (score -1):

If you need a ordrered view, you have to use `Top 100 percent`

```sql
CREATE VIEW LastName_vProductLinesUSA 
AS SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [ ProductID ], [ Name ], [ ProductModel ], [ Description ] 
FROM [ SalesLT.vProductAndDescription ] 
ORDER BY [ Description ] ;
```

Comment: Nope - rows in a table or view or resultset have no defined order. If you need an order within a resultset, the query creating that resultset must have an order by clause. This "trick" does not fool the optimizer - it will be ignored.

Comment: From my 20 years of TSql, it worked every time I did this for external program reading from my views (Eg: Excel, or other external tool). I know that for JOIN the view wont be sorted, but If you *really* need to have a default sort when using SELECT * FROM viewName, then it will always work